# 'Success'/'updated' message depending on action

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've got my sql query:

Whops, you're right. Here's the whole code:

```
<?php
//variables here

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Results (...)
    VALUES (...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (...)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Saved.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

How to show message "Success" when data is inserted or a message "Updated" when data is updated?

Comment: MySQL isn't going to show you any messages other than the number of rows changed. Where are you running that query?

Comment: @tadman, whops, you're right. I updated code.

Comment: Ah, that looks a lot better. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) you can detect whether a row was inserted or a row was modified:

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and
>   0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

I have successfully used this in PDO but I cannot confirm that it works in msyqli as well. I am pretty sure that it would though.

So you would have to check the return value of `$conn->affected_rows`:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    if ($conn->affected_rows === 1) {
        // new row inserted
    } else {
        // row found and possibly modified, you can filter for 0 or 2
        // if you need more details.
    }
} else {
    ...
```